# Creating local branch and rebasing it to master

Tags: git

I am sure there is already lots of discussions of this but we had a long discussion of this at work and there was no clear answer which is the right way to do this. We came up with two different techniques and maybe there is even more ways you can handle this situation.

First way:

```
git clone master
git checkout -b dev_branch
[do some changes, commit]
[master branch changed]
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout dev_branch
git rebase master
git push master
```

Second way:

```
git clone master
git checkout -b dev_branch
[do some changes, commit]
[master branch changed]
git checkout master
git pull
git rebase --onto master master dev_branch
git push master
```

Is there something wrong to push from local development branch to the actual master in this case?

Comment: The second one won't do anything. You are rebasing anything on `master` since `dev_branch` onto `master` again.

Comment: What do you mean? If I have changes in dev_branch and I want them to be rebased on the new changes in remote master, isn't this working?

Comment: @drodil That's not how `--onto` syntax works. For what you're trying to do, you'd need `git rebase --onto master master dev_branch` (the 2x `master` there is intentional). However, note that this results in `rebase` doing a `checkout dev_branch` as its first action, and thus is really redundant compared to both your first example and the more optimal workflow I gave in my answer.

Comment: @Amber Oh. So I should only use git rebase dev_branch in the second case without --onto?

Comment: No, you shouldn't try to rebase while on `master` at all. Rebase always operates on the current branch; it just has an option that lets you tell it to switch the current branch first.

Comment: @CharlesBailey yeah they are the same but I am just wondering if it's against git policies to push to master from local dev_branch?

Comment: @drodil: Git's just a tool; you can choose your own policies. When you make a clone all your branches are local "dev branches"; there's no functional or practical difference which one (if any) you choose to push from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not skip then unnecessary checkout of `master`?

```
git clone
git checkout -b dev_branch
[do some changes, commit]
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: I find myself using `HEAD:master` all the time. Good to see that I'm not alone in recommending it.